# Error 500: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 500 - HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, websphere, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

my task is to download an attachment from an IBM server.
The problem is that when I do the request with C# - HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse, I always get the status code 500 and the response body "Error 500: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 500". But!, when I do the same request with "Postman" there is no error and the file is downloaded. 
Please pay attention to the fact, that a cookie, which represents the current session, is needed. I added the same cookie (cookie can be reused) to Postman and to my request.

Here is the Http raw request of Postman (I would have posted a screen shot but am lacking reputation points):

**https://eforms.ebase.dlh.de:443/forms/secure/org/run/service/ContentStorageService44084**

**GET /forms/secure/org/run/service/ContentStorageService44084 HTTP/1.1
Host: eforms.ebase.dlh.de:443
Cookie: IPCZQX03e54bbd1d=090038003914048a6f27dcb2bc9b9e0c3a6c63b0; path=/; domain=dlh.de**

Postman works (it's really a very simple GET request with only two headers).

And here is the C# code (which returns me the "Error 500: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 500")

```
                HttpWebRequest req = null;
                HttpWebResponse res = null;

                req= (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://eforms.ebase.dlh.de:443/forms/secure/org/run/service/ContentStorageService44084");

                req.Headers.Add("Cookie", "IPCZQX03e54bbd1d=090038003914048a6f27dcb2bc9b9e0c3a6c63b0; path=/; domain=dlh.de");
                req.Host = "eforms.ebase.dlh.de";
                req.Method = "GET";

                try
                {
                    res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                }
                catch (WebException ex)
                {
                    res = (HttpWebResponse) ex.Response;
                }

                Stream receiveStream = res.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8); 

                string responseBody = sr.ReadToEnd(); 

                Console.WriteLine((int)res.StatusCode + "\t" + res.StatusCode.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
```

Any hints will be very much apreciated.

PS: the cookie is OK, without valid cookie I wouldn't even get the "Error 500: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 500". So the error message is from the IBM server, this I can tell for sure.

Thank you in advance.

Johann Kovalenko

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution. I had to pretend that I am a well-known browser.
So by adding

```
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)";
```

the server returned me the file.